# jquery multiselect: count for non selected options not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to count not selected  in multi select. But there seems to be some problem. See Fiddle for more ..

**Problems:**

1. Try clicking `Select all` and `Deselect all` buttons few times, and `Select all` stops working.
2. Even though `Select all` stops working visually, it is still selecting/deselecting in dom.you can use firebug to check it.
3. If it is Selecting/Deselecting in dom, why it  gives incorrect count for deselected elements ?

**NOTE:**

Kindly follow this exact order at fiddle below to see my problem.
Click on `Select all` then `Deselect all`  and then again `Select all`.
At this point DOM/Firebug shows options are selected.
But when I press count I get result 4 instaed of 0.

**OBJECTIVE:** I dont care if it is selecting visually or not, my main purpose is to get correct count for non-selected options as firebug shows "options" are being selected and deselected.

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/fgfdb/

**HTML:**

```
<button id="countdeselected">Count deselected</button>
<button id="selectall">select All</button>
<button id="deselectall">Deselect All</button>
<select name="languages[]" multiple="multiple" class="multiselect" id="languages" style=" ">
    <option value="ALB">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZA">Algeria</option>
    <option value="alfa">Custom1</option>
    <option value="beta">Custom2</option>
</select>
<ul id="status"></ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#countdeselected").click(function (event) {
    var dd = $("#languages option:not(:selected)").length
    $('#status').append($('<li>').text(dd));

});

$("#selectall").click(function (event) {
    $("#languages option").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
$("#deselectall").click(function (event) {
    $("#languages option").attr('selected', null);
});
```

Comment: On Chrome, it works well. But on Firefox, once you press Select All and then Deselect All, you can't press Select All button from now on. Pretty weird.

Comment: But it works if you press Select All and then Deselect All, then if you manually select all items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference between an attribute and a property of an element. The attribute is the initial state, and the property is the current state.

You are setting the attribute of the options, which only works when the element doesn't have the attribute to begin with. After that the property takes over and setting the attribute has no effect on the current state any more.

When you want to change the selection state, you want to set the property instead of the attribute:

```
$("#selectall").click(function (event) {
    $("#languages option").prop('selected', true);
});
$("#deselectall").click(function (event) {
    $("#languages option").prop('selected', false);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/fgfdb/3/